# production of HCl I have a long question

Tags: acid-base

SO chlorine gas bubbled through water produces HCl acid. Presumably the chlorine ions split open the Hydrogen off the H2O molecule so what happens to the OH- radical produced why doesnt that reduce the pH of that solution seeking out further created protons in solution turning them back into water again changing the ph from say 2 back to 7

Comment: Under intense light, some of what you describe may happen. But actually, $\ce{Cl2}$ will disproportionate to $\ce{Cl-}$, $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{HOCl}$.

Comment: Thanks for contributing to be fair this was a strange fever dream idea running through my head at 4am so I appreciate sense thanks again

Answer (score 1):

> When dissolved in water, chlorine gives an equilibrium mixture of chlorine, hypochlorous acid ($\ce{HOCl}$), and hydrochloric acid ($\ce{HCl}$):
>
> $$\ce{Cl2 + H2O <=> HOCl + HCl}$$
>
> In acidic solution, the major species are $\ce{Cl2 and HOCl}$ whereas in alkaline solution, effectively only $\ce{ClO-}$ (hypochlorite ion) is present (this is chlorine bleach). Very small concentrations of $\ce{ClO2-, ClO3-, and ClO4-}$ are also found. (source: Wikipedia)

Comment: Please don't simply copy text from Wikipedia, as it might be considered plagiarism. Could you add a link to the specific article you took the text from?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_chlorination

Comment: I thought giving the reference disproved plagiarism.